# nodejs wait error before return a function value

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, try-catch

I want to wait an error before returning value in a function. 
My code:

```js
async function CheckIfManagerIsInServer(client, server_id, member) {
    let isIn = { isIn: true, isNotIn: [] };

    if (CheckIfIsInChain(server_id)) {
        database.chains.forEach(chain => {
            if(chain.membersID.includes(server_id)) {
                chain.membersID.forEach(async server => {

                    client.guilds.cache.get(server)?.members.fetch(member).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err)
                        console.log("not exists")
                        isIn.isIn = false;
                        isIn.isNotIn.push(server)

                        console.log(isIn)
                        return;
                    })

                })
            }
        })

        console.log(isIn)
    }

    console.log(isIn)

    return await Promise.resolve(isIn);
}
```

As you can see, there is a catch.
The catch gets triggered when function has already returned `isIn`.
How I can wait? 
Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english!

Comment: `Promise.resolve(isIn);` does not mean "give me a promise that will magically resolve when something changes `isIn`". What you really need to wait for are the asynchronous `.fetch(member)` calls in those loops.

Answer (score 0):

use try catch , something like below

```
try {
await client.guilds.cache.get(server)?.members.fetch(member);
} catch(err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        console.log("not exists")
                        isIn.isIn = false;
                        isIn.isNotIn.push(server)

                        console.log(isIn)
                        return;
                    }
```

If you want to perform the operation in sequence, you cannot use forEach indeed. Just use a modern for … of loop instead, in which await will work as expected